# Sorting Gridview with Entity Framework Not Working as Intended

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview that i want to sort. I wrote the following method for it:

```
private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
    {
        var constr = new AdminRequirementEF();
        string sort = string.Concat("it.", sortExpression, " ", direction);
        int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddPageSize.SelectedItem.Text);

        var results = constr.Projects;
        int totalRecords = results.Count();
        this.PopulatePager(totalRecords, pageIndex);

        var sortedResults = constr.Projects.OrderBy(sort).Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageNum).ToList();
        grdMain.DataSource = sortedResults;
        grdMain.DataBind();
    }
```

The problem is sorting is applied on totalrecords not on per page filtered records. I want to use OrderBy(sort) after applying skip and take but it gives me an error stating skip can not be applied before orderby clause. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which EF version is this? This should work alright. What does the generated SQL look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the constr.Projects collection sorted on its primary key

var results = constr.Projects.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectId)

and then apply the skip and take on the 'results' collection with sorting.

results = results.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageNum).OrderBy(sort).ToList();

This way you will get the records for particular page sorted as required.

Comment: No its not working, tried this before.I guess Orderby(string value) cant be applied after Skip-Take.